# How to implement MVC unobtrusive validation on a field that accepts multiple emails addresses

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, email, unobtrusive-validation

I had created a MVC web application for the sales team to use to enter prospects into the system while simultaneously sending them a follow up message. One requirement was the ability to carbon copy multiple prospects on the message being sent.

The rest of the application was using unobtrusive validation which works great on standard HTML5 input types such as "email". The problem is that there is not a standard input type that will automatically validate multiple email addresses like you'd see in an email application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the create a custom validation attribute and register it with the client side so it can be validated unobtrusively.

1. Create custom validation attribute:

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   namespace CustomValidation.BLL {
       public class MultiEmailValidator : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable{

           protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
               return new ValidationResult("");
           }

           public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
               ModelClientValidationRule mvr = new ModelClientValidationRule();
               mvr.ErrorMessage = "Enter valid email addresses separated by semi-colons.";
               mvr.ValidationType = "multiemail";

               return new[] { mvr };
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register custom validation on the client side:

   ```
   $(function () { 
       jQuery.validator.addMethod('multiemail', function (value, element, params) {            
           // emails should be separated by either ';' or ','
           var email = value.split(/[;,]+/);
           valid = true;

           // call the standard jquery validator method on each email entered
           for (var i in email) {
               value = email[i];
               valid = valid && jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(value), element);
           }
           return valid;
       }, '');

       jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('multiemail', function (options) {
           options.rules['multiemail'] = {};
           options.messages['multiemail'] = options.message;
       });
   }(jQuery));
   ```
3. Set attribute on the model:

   ```
   [Display(Name = "Carbon Copy")]        
   [MultiEmailValidator]
   public string CarbonCopy { get; set; }
   ```
4. Add input to view:

   ```
   <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
       @Html.LabelFor(p => p.CarbonCopy, new { @class = "sr-only" })

       @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.CarbonCopy, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @placeholder = "Carbon Copy" })

       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.CarbonCopy)
   </div>
   ```

Result:
[Invalid Emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvSPe.png)

Result:
[Valid Emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T2U8.png)